# Invalid PNG signature FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, png, video-codecs

I am using FFmpeg to generate a video from a set of images in .png format.

I used the below command to extract the images from a video.

```
ffmpeg -i RGB.mkv -map 0:0 -vsync 0 -c:v copy RGB-%04d.png
```

I used the below command to generate the video from images.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i RGB-%04d.png -s 2048x1536 rg1.mkv
```

which gives me the following error:

```
[png @ 000001cfd8d4a440] Invalid PNG signature 0xFFD8FFDB00C50002.
[...]
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Extract images:

```
ffmpeg -i RGB.mkv RGB-%%4d.png
```

Image sequence to video:

```
ffmpeg -i RGB-%%4d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -s 2048:1536 RG1.mkv
```

Change pixel format to suit.

Comment: The second run without any issue, but I am not able to play the video using Azure Kinect Viewer v1.4.1

Comment: I received two warnings when I executed the first command: `1. [matroska,webm @ 000001d3fe6731c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Attachment: none): unknown codec Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options` 

2. `[swscaler @ 000001d3fe71c5c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set the range correctly` The command ran and I can see the images

Comment: Could not replicate your first errors, even with h265. Regarding playback. Have you tested in Windows Media Player or similar. I have no issues with playback. My guess is it is a compatibility issue with Kinect Viewer.

Comment: I tested it on the VLC media player, and it works.